# alpha blending in opengl es not working

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to vary the transparency of a texture drawn onto a quad, the code below works fine except the alpha set with glColor4f has no effect. What are the possible reasons for this? Is it likely to be a gl setting somewhere else in the program?

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.3f);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadNormals);
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadTexCoords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&modelViewProjectionButton.data[0] );
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_QUAD_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, quadIndices);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
```

Edit:
I managed to do it as per the answer below. If anyone's interested, i put a uniform variable in my shader, called alpha, like this:

```
uniform float alpha;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord);
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * alpha;
}
```

and then when i'm drawing the scene i used it like this (for example to set 0.5 alpha):

```
GLint alphaLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "alpha");
glUniform1f(alphaLocation, 0.5);
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I was implying. Though you do actually have two choices when doing this, you could use a uniform in the vertex shader and set a varying to pass to the fragment shader (this is effectively how the fixed-function pipeline works with `glColor (...)`). Using the uniform in the fragment shader is much more straight-forward however, especially since when you think about it the alpha value is **uniform**, so there is no point in using per-vertex interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obviously using OpenGL ES 2.0 (because you are using `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glUniformMatrix4fv`), which actually makes this a bit puzzling. OpenGL ES 2.0 does not define `glColor<N> (...)`, this was part of the fixed-function API and should not be defined in a compliant OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation.

Even if it is defined, there is no mechanism in GLSL ES to get the "current color" in a shader. Desktop GL has the pre-declared variable `gl_Color` in compatibility GLSL profiles, but GLSL ES does not.

You will need to use a GLSL uniform if you want to define the color this way instead of using a per-vertex attribute.

Comment: great, thanks - any pointers on how i would use a GLSL uniform to achieve this?